# Flutter: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am currently having a problem trying to allow a user to create an account through my application using firebase authentication. Method: 
createUserWithEmailAndPassword()

Error: 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

I had to migrate my application to Android X because i was using Firestore as my Database and everything was working well till it came time to test the creating of an account. I have tried everything from changing dependencies in my build.gradle file to changing the versions of the plugins in the pubspec.yaml file. Nothing is working. I have also enabled sign in with email and password in the firebase console.

Pubspec plugins currently being used:

```
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  cloud_firestore: ^0.9.0
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.1+3
  firebase_auth: ^0.9.0
  location: "^2.3.5"
  geolocator: ^4.0.0
```

Firebase auth code:

```
FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
 Future<FirebaseUser> handleRegistration (String *,
  String *,String *, String *, String *,
  String *, String *, String *, String *, 
  String *, String *, String *,
  String medName, String medNum, String emrgName, 
  String emrgNum,  String emailAdd,String password) async{
    try{
      final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: emailAdd,password: password);
      assert(user != null);
      assert(await user.getIdToken()!= null);
      if(user!= null){
        getLocation();
      if(await user.getIdToken() != null){
        if(isMember == "Yes"){
          String validateMembership = checkUsersClubReg(user.uid, clubName);
          if(validateMembership == "Active"){
            var clubDetails = validateMembership.split(',');
            createUsersAccount(*, *, *, *, *,
             *, *, *, *, *, *, "*",
              *, user.uid, medName, medNum, emrgName, emrgNum,"Inactive","0" );
          }else{
            createUsersAccount(*, *, *, *, *,
             *, *, *, *, *, *, "*",
              *, user.uid, medName, medNum, emrgName, emrgNum,"Inactive","0");
          }
        }
      }
      return user;
    }
    }on AuthException catch(ex){
      print(ex.code.toString());

    }
  }
```

Expected result: Users account is written to firebase authentication 
Actual Result: 
Code breaks, error:
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: sorry for the asterisks, i had to hide some information

Comment: did you find any solution regarding this

Comment: No unfortunately not, i converted the entire project back to using the realtime database instead of the cloud firestore